# What does urllib2.Request(<url>) do and how do i print/view it

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn how urllib2 works and how it encapsulates its various components before sending out an actual request or response.

So far I have:

```
theurl = "www.example.com"
```

That obviously specifies the URL to look at.

```
req = urllib2.Request(theurl)
```

Don't know what this does, hence the question.

```
handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

This one gets the page and does all the requests and responses required.

So my question is, what does urllib2.Request actually do?

To try and look at it to get an idea I tried

```
print req
```

and just got

```
<urllib2.Request instance at 0x123456789>
```

I also tried

```
print req.read()
```

and got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?  
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/urllib2.py, line 207, in `__`getattr`__`  
        raise AttributeError, attr  
AttributeError: read
```

So I'm obviously doing something wrong. If anyone can help in one of both my questions that would be great.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

Comment: @Blair, last I checked python's `urllib2` docs were not so great... Michael Foord has a pretty good docset here: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml

Comment: -3? Man, that's harsh. How about up-voting a few questions instead?

Comment: What is harsh here? The OP is obviously not interested doing basic research itself.

Comment: What's harsh is that I think he's getting the message about the quality of his question, whether the rating is -1, -2 or lower. There's no reason to kick the OP when he's already down, especially when more productive time can be spent voting up the many many good questions on SO that deserve it but are languishing on ratings of 0 or 1. If you think this isn't a problem with SO, go listen to the StackExchange podcasts and search for the issue on Meta. Rant over.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The class "Request" you're asking about: 
http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request

> class urllib2.Request(url[, data][,
>   headers][, origin_req_host][,
>   unverifiable])
>
> This class is an abstraction of a URL
>   request.

The function you actually want to make a request (which can accept a `Request` object or wrap one around a URL string you provice) constructing a Request object): http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen

> urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][,timeout])
>   Open the URL url, which can be either a string or a Request object.

Example:

```
theurl = "www.example.com"
try:
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(theurl)
    print resp.read()
except IOError as e:
    print "Error: ", e
```

Example 2 (with `Request`):

```
theurl = "www.example.com"
try:
    req = urllib2.Request(theurl)
    print req.get_full_url()
    print req.get_method()
    print dir(req)  # list lots of other stuff in Request
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    print resp.read()
except IOError as e:
    print "Error: ", e
```

Answer (score 4):

`urllib2.Request()` looks like a function call, but isn't - it's an object constructor. It creates an object of type Request from the urllib2 module, documented [here](http://code.reddit.com/docs/urllib2.Request-class.html).

As such, it probably doesn't do anything except initialise itself. You can verify this by looking at the source code, which should be in your Python installation's lib directory (urllib2.py, at least in Python 2.x).

Comment: Thanks for the replys. 

@S.Lott - I was more interested in the purpose of Request. Reading the handle is further down the chain than I wanted to see.

@Bliar - Thanks for the direction, I had looked there but as Mike said it's description if very poor.

@Maike - Thanks for the link, that's the explaination I was after. It makes sense now.

Still not sure why I can't print/view the contents of the Request object.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but, same as S.Lott, it does not provide me with the info I wish to see. Printing "handle" just prints the collected web page. I wish to see "req" and how it uses "theurl" and any other inputs it's given, before it's put into urlopen. @Sentinel- having a good day are we :). It looks like you're the one lacking the basic research.

Comment: Excellent, Example 2 is very helpful and allows me to see what I was hoping to. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, this isn't the comment section for the whole page, just my answer. "Example 2" is from the other answer (by dkamins). Click the 'add comment' link below that answer to comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the constructed URL in the `Request` object use :

```
print(urllib2.Request.get_full_url())
```